# CSS Background Color of ::before element not showing

Tags: html, css

I'm following some tutorials to do some coding, and I've found that for some reason, when i use the ::before pseudo attribute, and try to set the background color of it, nothing is visible.

```
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #1d061a;
    font-family: consolas;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 40px 0;
}

.container .box {
    position: relative;
    width: 320px;
    height: 400px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 40px 30px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.container .box::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    transform: skewX(15deg);
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

(I couldn't figure out how to get the code to display correctly)

Comment: Can you share the link to the tutorial, please?

Answer (score 1):

Little syntax error; all that was missing was a " ; " after your `height` declaration in the `::before` selector, causing your `background-color` to not be picked up.

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #1d061a;
    font-family: consolas;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 40px 0;
}

.container .box {
    position: relative;
    width: 320px;
    height: 400px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 40px 30px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.container .box::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    transform: skewX(15deg);
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got some error in your `::before` missing a `;` after height declaration.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #1d061a;
  font-family: consolas;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 40px 0;
}

.container .box {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 40px 30px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background: #f00;
}

.container .box::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transform: skewX(15deg);
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```